# jQuery .css("opacity", "+=0.1") behaving weirdly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I made this little 'etch a scetch' type thing and I wanted to make opacity increase by a bit up to full opacity every time mouseenter event gets triggered. 
I got everything working, but for the life of me I can't figure out why doesn't the opacity go all the way up to 1.

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "td", function () {
    $(this).css("background","black").css({
        opacity: function (index, value) {
            return parseFloat(value) + 0.1;
        }
    }); 
});
```

CSS:

```
td, tr {       
    opacity:0.5;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
```

If I set the css to 1, mouseenter event makes it completely black. If it's 0.5, mouseenter starts at 0.5 and goes to '1' in debugg, but in reality it just looks like 0.7.
and if i remove `.css("background","black")` and/or add `background:black;` in CSS.  The code doesn't do anything.

[Link to the full code](http://jsfiddle.net/bitvala/hSgh8/3/)

Comment: It does increase to 1 and even goes past 1. http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/hSgh8/6/   0.6
0.7000000238418579
0.8000000476837158
0.9000000715255737
1.0000000953674317
1.1
1.1
1.1

Comment: Make sure you don't increase the `opacity` above `1`: `function (index, value) { var prevVal = parseFloat(value); return prevVal + (prevVal < 1 ? 0.1 : 0); }`

Comment: `<button id="myButt">Magic!</button>` ... -dissolves into fits of immature giggles-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have an opacity of 50% set on the `tr`, so even if you have an opacity of 100% on the `td`, it will be faded by the row. Just split the CSS :

```
td,tr {

    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
td{
    opacity : 0
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/hSgh8/5/

Comment: oh my god, how did this miss me.... thank yu so much!! I was looking at it for two hours

Answer (score 0):

You're only updating the opacity on the `td` so while it is totally opaque, the `tr` containing it is still at 50% opacity, and therefore the whole thing is 50%